# Using attributes in C# to check authorization of user

Tags: c#, attributes, authorization

I would like to check authorization on a method for the current user to check if he/she has the right to perform this action.

Here is the example of the attribute I have in place:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class IsAuthorized : Attribute
{
    public IsAuthorized(Rights right)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = false;

        if (right == Rights.None)
            isAuthorized = true;
        else
        {
            DataAccessLayer.IDAL dal = new DataAccessLayer.DAL();
            string userName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
            Guid userID = dal.GetUserIDFromUserName(userName);

            isAuthorized = dal.HasRight(userID, right.ToString());
        }

        if (!isAuthorized)
            throw new SecurityException("You don't have the rights to perform this action");
    }
}
```

And this is how I how like to check if the user has the authority to access the method:

```
[IsAuthorized(Rights.CreateUserGroup)]
public string Ping()
{
   return "The service is online";
}
```

Comment: Which technology ? MVC ? ASP.NET ? WPF ?

Comment: Sounds like a potential job for [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). This also reminds me of CAS. Although I'm not sure I agree with baking permissions into the metadata of the code versus a code-free configuration route.

Comment: I am using a WCF web service